# What is the criteria of name "Axiom"?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm confused in criteria of name "Axiom". Why we call '-st countability axiom' 'Axiom'? Isn't just property of some topological properties? Also, why don't we call continuum hypothesis continuum axiom?

Comment: The continuum hypothesis indeed should be called an axiom. I believe it was called a hypothesis once and people just continued to call it that way, even though it was proved that it is independent of the ZFC axioms.

Comment: Convention, tradition, ...

Comment: [Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom): "a statement that is taken to be true, to serve as a premise or starting point for further reasoning and arguments. ". Originally, [CH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) was so called "because Cantor believed it to be true and for many years tried in vain to prove it."

Comment: I had heard about independency of 'continuum hypothesis' with ZFC. Then, was it proved about independency of Axiom of choice with ZF?

Comment: The Axiom of choice, the well-ordering theorem and Zorn's lemma are all equivalent, and conventionally considered to be axioms, regardless of their names. And yes, they are independent of ZF.

Comment: @Mark Having proved it is independent, if you want to assume that the continuum hypothesis is true you can add it as an axiom. But it would be equally consistent to add its negation as an axiom - and if you care about it, you have to choose which option you want.

Comment: I think many mathematicians now might relegate axioms (as opposed to definitions) to being more at the fundamental set theoretic level, but the word still floats around in various contexts for historical reasons.

Comment: @Arthur The statements equivalent to the "Axiom of choice" could be considered to be axioms when they are assumed to be true (in algebraic contexts Zorn's Lemma is often the easiest formulation to work with). They could also be considered to be false, in which case they would not be axioms.

Comment: @Mark Bennet This is true. My point is that the name hypothesis is wrong. You can't prove it and you can't prove its negation. You can only assume one of them.

Comment: @Mark But when it was first proposed it was a hypothesis, hence the name ...

Comment: @Mark Bennet I know. It was a hypothesis, but now the name is not really correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "axiom" is often used as a list of properties that define a type of structure. For example, the definition of a group is often referred to as the group axioms, the Peano axioms define how the natural numbers behave and the complete ordered field axioms define how the real numbers behave. Similarly, we have axioms that describe how a topological space behaves (the axioms of topology) as well as for stronger notions like T1-space, Hausdorff space, regular space, and all of that.

This use isn't really in conflict with how "axiom" is used as a general assumption about our foundations, e.g. the axioms of set theory. The ZFC axioms are properties that a universe of sets obeys. That we view a universe of sets as a background on which all the ensuing mathematics takes place invites us to frame this as an "absolute" assumption about all of mathematics, but it's really not so different in character.

If we want to assume the CH for whatever reason, we are working with a stronger notion of set theory than just the ZFC axioms, since the ZFC axioms don't imply it, just like if we want to assume Hausdorff-ness we are working with a stronger notion of topological space than the usual three axioms.

The difference is that since topology is founded on set theory, when we assume CH, we get a whole bunch of new theorems about topology. And since not everyone agrees that the CH is a valid requirement about how sets should behave (and in fact most would disagree), it's convention to state explicitly that CH was an assumption, and to not view the theorem as absolutely true, but rather as a result relative to CH.

The same is true (to a much lesser extent) with the axiom of choice, which is independent of the other axioms of ZFC. Although most mathematicians view it as a correct requirement about how sets should behave, due to historical controversy and its non-constructive character, it is often at least remarked upon when a result uses it. And the necessity of the use (and also "how much choice" is used) is often scrutinized.

As to why CH is not called an axiom, it is often called one in my experience. I would guess the reason why its "official name" doesn't have the word 'axiom' in it is mostly historical: for a good amount of time since Cantor originated it, it was viewed as a very important open question that would eventually be proven or refuted. Now we know it's independent of ZFC, so the name 'axiom' is not so inappropriate. Though as I mentioned above is not an axiom that is seen as "fair game" to assume like the ZFC axioms, it is just one of many axioms beyond ZFC it might be interesting to investigate the consequences of.

Answer (score 1):

Axiom mean something that occur without proof .

So for example a definition doesn't need to have a proof therefore we can call it an axiom.

But the real notion of axiom is a proposition which is logically  independent to the theory( and that we accept by intuition\curiosity to be true)  i.e  a proposition $P$ is the such that $P$ and $not(P) $ not have a  proof ...

And the continuum hypothesis is a proposition of this form
The reason that we don't call continuum hypothesis continuum axiom is firstly by convention and history secondly since it's not accepted by all the mathematician community...

Godel incompleteness theorem state (not formally at all) that all theory which can speak about arithmetic have a independent proposition !!

Comment: A statement which could be false is not an axiom, because an axiom is a statement assumed to be true. If an independent statement is assumed to be true this is equivalent to taking it as an axiom.

Comment: You right I will add

Comment: @postmortes Have you ever looked at the definitions in Euclid, some of which seem to me to have mathematical content?

Comment: So the fact we prove the axiom of choice from Zorn's Lemma? And that we prove Zorn's Lemma from the Well Ordering Theorem?

Comment: Martin's axiom is called an axiom even though "it's not accepted by all the mathematician community..."